# Using hibernate3-maven-plugin to generate Sequence Scripts

Tags: hibernate, code-generation, sequence

I am using hibernate3-maven-plugin version 2.0 hbm2ddl to generate SQL scripts from code. I am using  process-classes. I my Entity class I am using a sequence.
@SequenceGenerator(name="sessionSeq", sequenceName="SESSION_SEQ", allocationSize=50, initialValue=1)
When I run the Maven script, this generates  create sequence hibernate_sequence; I wanted it to generate something like  create sequence hibernate_sequence increment by 50;

Can someone help me?

I am using the following jars :
hibernate-tools - 3.2.4.GA, hibernate-core - 3.6.1.Final, hibernate-entitymanager - 3.6.1.Final, hibernate-validator - 4.1.0.Final, hibernate-validator-legacy - 4.0.2.GA and DB related jars.

The hbm2ddl is not picking up the allocationSize=50 property of the @SequenceGenerator when I am trying to generate the .SQL file.

This is an extract of the code:

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="sessionInfoIdSeq", sequenceName="SESSIONINFO_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=50)

public class SessionInfo {

```
@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="sessionInfoIdSeq")
private Integer          id;
```

Comment: I tried using the SchemaExport class as defined in the blog http://www.java-tutorial.ch/hibernate/generate-ddl-with-hibernate.

Comment: The output generated was 

drop table UserEntity cascade constraints;
drop sequence main.attachment_id_seq;
create table UserEntity (id number(10,0) not null, password varchar2(255 char), userName varchar2(255 char), primary key (id));
create sequence main.attachment_id_seq;

This was not what I expected. I wanted the allocationSize to be reflected in the Sequence definition.

Comment: Checked the API for hibernate-core-3.6.1 Final which is being used by the SchemaExport API.
The SequenceGenerator.java class that was getting called from this jar was using a deprecated method from the Dialect class which was generating the Sequence Definition. The method was public String[]  getCreateSequenceStrings(String sequenceName), instead if it would use the String  getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName, int initialValue, int incrementSize) from the Dialect class, it would have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the API for hibernate-core-3.6.1 Final which is being used by the SchemaExport API.
The SequenceGenerator.java class that was getting called from this jar was using a deprecated method from the Dialect class which was generating the Sequence Definition. The method was public String[]  getCreateSequenceStrings(String sequenceName), instead if it would use the String  getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName, int initialValue, int incrementSize) from the Dialect class, it would have solved my problem.